# How do I set the dropdown height of an Infragistics UltraCombo?

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, infragistics

I want to set the dropdown height of an Infragistics `UltaCombo` so that a user won't have to scroll down to see all of the available options.

I see that there is a `DropDownWidth` property, but can't seem to find anything for height. Is it something I'm missing? This is for a Winforms Application on .NET 4.5. I know that a `DropDownHeight` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exists for the standard WinForms `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem.

There is a `MaxDropDownItems` property that controls the number of items in the visible portion of the dropdown.

[MaxDropDownItems](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinEditors.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraComboEditor~MaxDropDownItems.html)